# All Animation are executing slowly

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, ios-simulator

I'm not sure what happened to the animation process. Suddenly my all animations are executing slowly. I've reset my `Simulator`, restarted my `Mac`, but doesn't help.

I'm not sure what I've done or its a system issue. Please check the below image. Every animation is executing slowly.

I'm using `Xcode7.3.1`, `Simulator iOS 9.3`. Its a simple `pushViewController` and nothing

[image]

Comment: Check slow animation is enabled or not (Press Cmd+T).

Comment: Where on simulator or on xcode

Comment: please check that in simulator

Comment: Yeah, it was enable. thanks works as before now. I don't know how that get enabled. May be by mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a minor problem. I think You have just checked the Slow Animation in simulator by mistake.
All you have to do is that Go to your `simulator>Debug>Slow Animation`

**Uncheck Slow Animation**

[image]

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of this, And don't know how it get enabled. Thanks working fine now

Comment: @AmitSingh in the above screenshot you can see that the shortcut is `⌘ T` which is the same shortcut you use when opening a new tab in Xcode...so maybe you was trying to open a new tab in Xcode...but the simulator had focus so you ended up toggling slow animations instead. Not that I have ever done this myself of course ;)

Comment: Yeah its possible, that to letting me know that. I was not aware of that slow motion feature in simulator :D. never check that option

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the Simulator First for Slow animation.

`Debug-->slow animation` OR  <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You may  have pressed <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Press again <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to remove slow Animations in your `Simulator`.