# Xcode 10.1 Simulator suddenly responding very very slowly

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I have been working on core Animation App (swift), until yesterday Simulator was responding perfectly. All of a sudden every animation in Simulator started showing extremely Slow. It made me very difficult to test my changes on simulator.

 - Xcode 10.1

 - Simulator iPhone 8 Plus 12.1

Please help to solve this problem

Comment: Got answer at 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321978/all-animation-are-executing-slowly

Hence closing this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you have activated Slow-Motion—This shortcut should do it:

```
Command ⌘ + T
```

Or:

[image: img]